# jQuery plugin to serialize a form and also restore/populate the form?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

Is there a jQuery plugin out there that can serialize a form, and then later restore/populate the form given the serialized value?  I know the form plugin can serialize as a querystring, but I haven't found anything that will restore the form from the querystring.

What I'd like to do is serialize the form values, store as a cookie whenever the form changes, and then restore the form from the cookie (if it exists) when the page first loads.

I have found pieces of this puzzle out there (form plugin, cookie plugin, various autosave plugins that don't restore), but before I cobble something together from various parts, I wanted to make sure there wasn't a nice canned solution waiting for me out there.

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's a little something I rolled based on work of others, specifically [serializeAnything](http://www.bram.us/2008/10/27/jqueryserializeanything-serialize-anything-and-not-just-forms/):

```
/* jQuery.values: get or set all of the name/value pairs from child input controls   
 * @argument data {array} If included, will populate all child controls.
 * @returns element if data was provided, or array of values if not
*/

$.fn.values = function(data) {
    var els = $(this).find(':input').get();

    if(typeof data != 'object') {
        // return all data
        data = {};

        $.each(els, function() {
            if (this.name && !this.disabled && (this.checked
                            || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName)
                            || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {
                data[this.name] = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        return data;
    } else {
        $.each(els, function() {
            if (this.name && data[this.name]) {
                if(this.type == 'checkbox' || this.type == 'radio') {
                    $(this).attr("checked", (data[this.name] == $(this).val()));
                } else {
                    $(this).val(data[this.name]);
                }
            }
        });
        return $(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow nice! Will save this for future use.

Comment: Very cool!  I'll just have to add a to/from JSON step so I can store the serialized state as a cookie.  Thanks!

Comment: Somebody need to make an official plugin from this :)

Comment: i expanded on this to support multiple checkboxes with same name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12218972/26188

Comment: Use $(this).prop() instead of $(this).attr() to set "checked" with jQuery>=1.6. https://api.jquery.com/prop/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Because empty fields could not be restored, I would change this line `if (this.name && data[this.name]) {` into `if (this.name && typeof data[this.name] != 'undefined') {`.

Comment: Can someone explain the `data[this.name] == $(this).val()` part for checkbox? I don't get it.

Answer (score 16):

Ive expanded upon Barnabas answer with the following:

1. Support multiple inputs with same name (checkboxes usually do this).
2. Cache selectors when possible, remove unneeded use of $

   ```
       /* jQuery.values: get or set all of the name/value pairs from child input controls   
        * @argument data {array} If included, will populate all child controls.
        * @returns element if data was provided, or array of values if not
       */

       $.fn.values = function(data) {
           var els = this.find(':input').get();

           if(arguments.length === 0) {
               // return all data
               data = {};

               $.each(els, function() {
                   if (this.name && !this.disabled && (this.checked
                                   || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName)
                                   || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {
                       if(data[this.name] == undefined){
                           data[this.name] = [];
                       }
                       data[this.name].push($(this).val());
                   }
               });
               return data;
           } else {
               $.each(els, function() {
                   if (this.name && data[this.name]) {
                       var names = data[this.name];
                       var $this = $(this);
                       if(Object.prototype.toString.call(names) !== '[object Array]'){
                           names = [names]; //backwards compat to old version of this code
                       }
                       if(this.type == 'checkbox' || this.type == 'radio') { 
                           var val = $this.val();
                           var found = false;
                           for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
                               if(names[i] == val){
                                   found = true;
                                   break;
                               }
                           }
                           $this.attr("checked", found);
                       } else {
                           $this.val(names[0]);
                       }
                   }
               });
               return this;
           }
       };
   ```

Comment: Could you possibly make a jsfiddle or similar to show in use?   I made a simple demo here http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/jsmya but I havent got the check/radio boxes working correctly

Comment: the reason you cant get it working is because you are doing it wrong :) check/radio buttons have values and thats what you save/set: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xKizw

Comment: You should be using `.prop` instead of `.attr`
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: This is great, for every one using this, remember to add "number" and "email" types too `|| /text|number|email|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {`

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Barnabas Kendall for initial function and Eggert Jóhannesson for radio button fix!

I encountered an issue with checkboxes, if they are not checked they won't be put into the array, so far so good. But as the state of checkboxes is not stored when they are not checked I couldn't restore this state if the user had checked them during editing the form.

So I extended the restore functionality to uncheck all checkboxes which are not in the data array, this will ensure the state of checkboxes is restored correctly no matter what was changed in the form before executing restore:

```
if (this.name && data[this.name]) {
   if(this.type == "checkbox" || this.type == "radio") {
       $(this).prop("checked", (data[this.name] == $(this).val()));
   } else {
       $(this).val(data[this.name]);
   }
} else if (this.type == "checkbox") {
   $(this).prop("checked", false);
}
```

Complete function:

```
$.fn.values = function(data) {
   var inps = $(this).find(":input").get();

    if(typeof data != "object") {
       // return all data
        data = {};

        $.each(inps, function() {
            if (this.name && (this.checked
                        || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName)
                        || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {
                data[this.name] = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        return data;
    } else {
        $.each(inps, function() {
            if (this.name && data[this.name]) {
                if(this.type == "checkbox" || this.type == "radio") {
                    $(this).prop("checked", (data[this.name] == $(this).val()));
                } else {
                    $(this).val(data[this.name]);
                }
            } else if (this.type == "checkbox") {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
       });
       return $(this);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A big thank you to Barnabas Kendall for his answer, very useful.

However I found 1 error in it regarding restoring radio buttons, where instead of selecting the correct one it just copied the saved value to all buttons in group.

Fortunately it's simple to fix.
Just replace

```
if(this.type == 'checkbox') {
```

With

```
if(this.type == 'checkbox' || this.type == 'radio') {
```

and it will correctly update radio buttons

Answer (score 3):

- Support multiple inputs with same name (checkboxes usually do this).
- Cache selectors when possible
- Return values for all inputs, if `checkbox` or `radio` isn't set, the value is `null`
- Deactivates `checkbox` or `radio` if value is `null`

  ```js
  $.fn.formData = function(values) {
    var form = $(this);
    var inputs = $(':input', form).get();
    var hasNewValues = typeof values == 'object';

    if (hasNewValues) {
      $.each(inputs, function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var value = values[this.name];

        if (values.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
          switch (this.type) {
            case 'checkbox':
              input.prop('checked', value !== null && value);
              break;
            case 'radio':
              if (value === null) {
                input.prop('checked', false);
              } else if (input.val() == value) {
                input.prop("checked", true);
              }
              break;
            default:
              input.val(value);
          }
        }
      });
      return form;
    } else {
      values = {};
      $.each(inputs, function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var value;
        switch (this.type) {
          case 'checkbox':
          case 'radio':
            value = input.is(':checked') ? input.val() : null;
            break;
          default:
            value = $(this).val();
        }
        values[this.name] = value;
      });
      return values;
    }
  };
  ```

  ```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my jQuery Populate plugin:

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/code/development/javascript/jquery-populate-plugin/

Populates all form elements as well as labels and any contained HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to handle this case: `<input name="this[is][my][input][]" />` - and you, the greedy guy, need the whole matrix parsed:

**To populate:**

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

**To retrieve values:**

Use `$('form').serialize()` and pass the results to this function:

http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str/

Answer (score 0):

To **serialize** into a string: `var s = $('form').first().serialize();`

To **restore** based on that string: `$('form').first().deserialize(s);`

Of course you'll need a derserialize plugin such as the one I [originally posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441276/1766230).

```
$.fn.deserialize = function (serializedString) 
{
    var $form = $(this);
    $form[0].reset();
    serializedString = serializedString.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
    var formFieldArray = serializedString.split("&");

    // Loop over all name-value pairs
    $.each(formFieldArray, function(i, pair){
        var nameValue = pair.split("=");
        var name = decodeURIComponent(nameValue[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(nameValue[1]);
        // Find one or more fields
        var $field = $form.find('[name=' + name + ']');

        // Checkboxes and Radio types need to be handled differently
        if ($field[0].type == "radio" || $field[0].type == "checkbox") 
        {
            var $fieldWithValue = $field.filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
            var isFound = ($fieldWithValue.length > 0);
            // Special case if the value is not defined; value will be "on"
            if (!isFound && value == "on") {
                $field.first().prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $fieldWithValue.prop("checked", isFound);
            } 
        } else { // input, textarea
            $field.val(value);
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441276/1766230

Here's a jsfiddle that let's you play around with setting values, clearing, resetting, and "deserializing": http://jsfiddle.net/luken/4VVs3/

Comment: Fails when there is Select field with "multiple" attribute.