# Remove plus sign (+) in URL query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying get the string in the following URL to display on my webpage.

http://example.com?ks4day=Friday+September+13th

*EDIT:* The date in the URL will change from person to person as it's merged in by my CRM program.

I can get it to display on my webpage using the code below, the problem is the plus signs (+) come through as well.

eg. Friday+September+13th

What I need it to do is replace the plus signs (+) with spaces so it looks like this:

eg. Friday September 13th

I'm new to this so I'm having some trouble working it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

**This is the code i'm using in a .js file**

```
      function qs(search_for) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
            return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

**This is the code i'm using on my webpage to make it display**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">document.write(qs("ks4day"));</script>
```

Comment: `str.replace('+', ' ');` would replace `+` with a space in the provided string.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("Is+it+friday+the+13th%3F").replace(/\+/g, " ")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all plus symbols in JavaScript String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485653/replacing-all-plus-symbols-in-javascript-string)

Comment: @SalmanA - Other way around: `decodeURIComponent("1+%2B+2+%3D+3".replace(/\+/g, '%20'))` otherwise you decode the "%2B" incorrectly

Comment: Woo Hoo. Got it working Using the decodeURIComponent. 

eg. <script type="text/javascript">document.write(decodeURIComponent(qs("ks4day")).replace(/\+/g, " "));</script>

Comment: @user2764485 You should do the `.replace(/\+/g, " ")` FIRST, not last, as @cloudfeet described above. Otherwise a properly-encoded plus sign will be replaced with a space, incorrectly!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If that's what you are doing, the plus sign will not be the only one that is going to give you a hard time. The apostrophe ('), equals (=), plus (+) and basically anything not in the permitted URL characters (see [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) @ Wikipedia) is going to get escaped.

**You are most likely looking for the [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) function.**

Comment: Also check documentation on decodeURI(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Comment: @SalmanA - You should replace "+" *before* decodeURIComponent, not after - otherwise you'll incorrectly decode "%2B" to " ".

Comment: Woo Hoo. Got it working Using the decodeURIComponent. eg. <script type="text/javascript">document.write(decodeURIComponent(qs("ks4day")).replace(/‌​\+/g, " "));</script>

Comment: What if you have a phone number with country code in that string? Replace is the worst possible option. decode doesn't remove pluses.

Comment: @Fratyr, could you please provide an example with phone number? As far as I see currently the proper answer will not have any issue with that.

Comment: @user2764485, You can't do a replace after decoding because you'll be decoding "%2b" to " ". And that is wrong.

Comment: @deb0rian I believe plus signs should be encoded as `%2B`. Plus signs are used to encode spaces in the query string so they should't be used literally.

Answer (score 143):

Although Bibhu's answer will work for this one case, you'll need to add `decodeURIComponent` if you have encoded characters in your URI string. You also want to make sure you do the replace before the decode in case you have a legitimate `+` in your URI string (as `%2B`).

I believe this is the best general way to do it:

```
var x = qs("ks4day");        // 'Friday+September+13th'
x = x.replace(/\+/g, '%20'); // 'Friday%20September%2013th'
x = decodeURIComponent(x);   // 'Friday September 13th'
```

Here's an example of when it might be useful:

```
var x = '1+%2B+1+%3D+2'; 
x = x.replace(/\+/g, '%20'); // '1%20%2B%201%20%3D%202'
x = decodeURIComponent(x);   // '1 + 1 = 2'
```

Comment: I found this question when looking for help specifically with plus signs. Even though I was already decoding with Node's unescape function, that function doesn't decode plus signs. This answer is the helpful one to me, and probably to most people who end up here.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the decodeURIComponent() function.

Comment: Perfectly working for me. It is avoiding of following changes when you are using ajax to get input values.       1). Space into plus sign.    2). plus sign into %20

Answer (score 12):

You can use replace() for this purpose

```
var dateString = 'Friday+September+13th';
var s = dateString .replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 12):

Parsing strings using regex is often prone to so many errors. Thankfully all modern browsers provide [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to handle params from url strings in a proper way:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var value = params.get('ks4day');
// "Friday September 13th"
```

Ps: There is also a good [polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params) for old browsers.

Comment: this is definitely the best answer, the other ones are at least outdated

Comment: Using native implementation is always best. For sure the best answer as of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring ?

```
import { parse } from 'querystring'; 
parse('ks4day=Friday+September+13th')
```

returns

```
{ 'ks4day': 'Friday September 13th' }
```

Assuming you are using something like Webpack that knows how to process import statements

Comment: Simple and best .