# How to get URL parameter using jQuery or plain JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, url, parameters, query-string, querystringparameter

I have seen lots of jQuery examples where parameter size and name are unknown.

My URL is only going to ever have 1 string:

```
http://example.com?sent=yes
```

I just want to detect:

1. Does `sent` exist?
2. Is it equal to "yes"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/979621

Comment: Best solution I've ever seen [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/3106590

Comment: There is now a plugin/library for this, called URI.js: https://github.com/medialize/URI.js

Comment: if you want a quick get by index: var value = document.referrer.substr(0, document.referrer.indexOf('&')).split('=')[1];

Answer (score 1449, accepted):

Best solution [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery).

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,
`http://dummy.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample`.

```
var tech = getUrlParameter('technology');
var blog = getUrlParameter('blog');
```

Comment: Thanks! But when copying this, I found a nasty surprise, involving a zero-width whitespace (\u200b) towards the end there. Making the script have an invisible syntax error.

Comment: How to convert the "+" inside parameter value into whitespaces?

Comment: Be careful, `;` is a [legal delimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure) which this doesn't account for.

Comment: Return a `false` or `null` for empty search

Comment: This solution works pretty well for me I've just used var sPageURL = decodeURI(window.location.search.substring(1)); to convert %20 characters into white spaces and also I return an empty string instead of nothing if the parameter is not matched.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript, location.search won't work for hash based routing (#)

Comment: To handle valueless params like `?param1&param2` modify the return to:
`return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];`

Comment: I would use "=== sParam" vs "== sParam" otherwise sParam = 'true' would match everything. Besides, always using === is a good idea period.

Comment: need to add  `sPageURL=decodeURIComponent(sPageURL);` to have special chars like **space** and **"** displayed correctly

Comment: Just to mention it - this script fragment also works without jQuery.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include all the comments code changes above this comment.

Comment: you can return empty string explicitly if no matches found - just before the last line of code.        return '';
    }; In that way all the code will return value

Comment: The decoding should be done on the parameter value (as Iouri suggests). If the decoding is done on the url (as in the answer), it won't work correctly if there's an encoded  `&` or `=` in a parameter value.

Comment: I needed to get a certain param from api generated data that was unpredictably separated sometimes by a question mark and sometimes an ampersand.  Replacing the third line of Kazi's code with this regex: sURLVariables = sPageURL.split(new RegExp('[\?&]')) works for me in that situation.

Comment: Since query string parameters are case insensitive, I think it would be better if when looking for a match with the parameter name provided the strings that are compared should be transformed to lower- or uppercase, e.g. if (sParameterName[0].toLowerCase() === sParam.toLowerCase())

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for multivalued keys (like `?technology=jquery&technology=css`).

Comment: I added `return false;` at the end of the function.

Comment: I think you shoud call decodeURIComponent on sParameterName[0] before comparing and on sParameterName[1] before returning, not on the whole string... What happens if a parameter name or value has an (encoded) '&' or '=' in it? You will do the wrong split!

Comment: I have some problem with this script so I have found better here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: It's actually wrong; you should urldecode parameters AFTER you have split the string, not before. Otherwise it will freak out if '&' or '=' are encoded there in the actual parameters.

Comment: you should use var window.location['pathname'] instead of window.location.search.substring(1) or else this will not work.

Comment: It works but is very inefficient. You're performing all the same work every time. Create an object that has a "params" list and that function as a method. When you call the function, populate the list of params. Then have a getter which returns items from the list.

If you're going to write a function that does the same thing each time, use RegEx, far faster, far more efficient

Comment: `var url = ` **new URI** `( ` **'http://example.com?sent=yes'** `);`
`var sendval = url.` **searchParams** ` (` 'sent' );` 
and you're done!

I down voted this.
Even if it's nice tempting and a good coding practice to write ya one homebrew function. Primary make use of functions ya library / framework offers, until you've good reason to do not.

Comment: I am missing something, what part of it is jquery, isnt this plain javascript?

Comment: Why do you name the function twice? Just delete the `var getUrlParameter = ` if you want to keep the function name

Comment: Fix @Nadu comment: `var url = new URL( 'http://example.com?sent=yes' ), sendval = url. searchParams.get('sent')` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Example

Comment: in my opinion, the code will be perfect if you change the IF condition to be :  

 ` if (decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[0]) === sParam || sParameterName[0] === sParam)  `

so that if we compare the variables that are already encoded as the arrays the condition "IF" will pass

Comment: `sParameterName[0]` should be `decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[0])`

Comment: 'here' link at the beginning of post is broken.

Comment: The `+` character represents a space, and is not handled by `decodeURIComponent()`. To support that specify: `decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]).replace(/\+/g, ' ')`

Answer (score 611):

Solution from **2024**

We have: http://example.com?sent=yes

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
```

Does *sent* **exist**?

```
searchParams.has('sent') // true
```

Is it **equal** to "yes"?

```
let param = searchParams.get('sent')
```

and then just compare it.

Last, if you have **multiple entries for the same parameter** (like ?id=1&id=2), you can use

```
let param = searchParams.getAll('id')
```

and it will return a list of values.

Comment: i think this is not supported across browsers so why should one use it? reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: @p_champ you are right. But you can use [polyfill for URLSearchParams](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params)

Comment: currently not working in IE / Edge, so do feature detection:

`if ('URLSearchParams' in window) { // Browser supports URLSearchParams}`
[See here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams?hl=en)

Comment: Good enough for me and my intended audience. https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Comment: Note this solutions is not clean code. It'll work **for get only**.
Try param.toString() on the current code. You'll get `http%3A%2F%2Fexample...`

So if you need to change the URL or like to be the correct and avoiding this kinda type violate do it like this:
Use `url=new URI(window.location.search)` Then `param =  url.searchParams;`  
The rest of the code above is fine.

Comment: @p_champ Edge got support in v17 (April 2018). Let IE die.

Comment: This is a modern solution to a modern problem.

Comment: If only IE 11 had support for this feature, how nice that'd be!! :)

Comment: According to the table linked by p_champ the only browser that doesn't support this at all is the InternetExplorer. All other current browsers can handle it. I like this solution as it is short and elegant.

Comment: I think that this is probably the best answer for modern browsers, and if you are need to support older browsers, you may consider using a polyfill, e.g., these: https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill or https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params

Comment: This is a great clean solution for 2022.  The surprise was learning about the Let verb.  Something new to understand.

Comment: @j.hull It's just another way to create a variable, but with slightly different behaviour (it won't get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). They added it because it's generally more useful (and less confusing!) for variables to only exist in the scope they were defined in (rather than the entire function). The name `let` has come from mathematics (like a lot of things in programming, actually). Those people like to say "let x equal the number of items in this set" or whatever.

Answer (score 235):

jQuery code snippet to get the dynamic variables stored in the url as parameters and store them as JavaScript variables ready for use with your scripts:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null) {
       return null;
    }
    return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
}
```

example.com?param1=name&param2=&id=6

```
$.urlParam('param1'); // name
$.urlParam('id');        // 6
$.urlParam('param2');   // null
```

example params with spaces

```
http://www.jquery4u.com?city=Gold Coast
console.log($.urlParam('city'));  
//output: Gold%20Coast



console.log(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('city'))); 
//output: Gold Coast
```

Comment: Note: You need to decode in case there are special characters as parameter or Umlaute etc. So instead of `return results[1] || 0;` it should be `return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;`

Comment: Just curious, why does it need the  `|| 0` part since there is already a check for the result, wouldn't it always return the match array ?

Comment: @AirWick219 an appropriate failsafe. though redundant, never hurts to be cautious

Comment: Here is, most likely, the original source: https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/  but this answer has some new ideas added

Comment: In my url, the params I need are hiding behind a `#` and *then* a second `?`. How can I modify the regex to find `harry` in this url?  `http://some.site.com/page.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4#e=5&f=6?g=harry`

Comment: @bgmCoder I hope you know by now why that wouldnt be possible? :D

Comment: @Tobias - not true.  I think I did figure out how to get that. If I remember right, I think I either regexed the last parameter or the entire url,

Comment: Not sure it's worth using jQuery for this.

Comment: Are you sure you need decodeURI followed by decodeURIComponent too?

Comment: This is a good approach. Can you provide one for javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: Meanwhile in 2020: Thank you for the correct regex - I was using an other one which did not work properly. Your's is working perfect for me!

Comment: There is a problem: try "?id=10&item_id=30" and then opposite - "?item_id=30&id=10". Compare results and you wull know something new ;-)

Answer (score 107):

I always stick this as one line. Now params has the vars:

```
params={};location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){params[k]=v})
```

multi-lined:

```
var params={};
window.location.search
  .replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
    params[key] = value;
  }
);
```

as a function

```
function getSearchParams(k){
 var p={};
 location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v})
 return k?p[k]:p;
}
```

which you could use as:

```
getSearchParams()  //returns {key1:val1, key2:val2}
```

or

```
getSearchParams("key1")  //returns val1
```

Comment: gives undefined for 

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-string-helper?fbclid=IwAR1kXjYCXYwo3APfeGgKIhZNteim7k5lv8LUI1epkV1FWIReU-kX4uxghQM`

Answer (score 54):

Yet another alternative function...

```
function param(name) {
    return (location.search.split(name + '=')[1] || '').split('&')[0];
}
```

Comment: This is wrong! For example `param('t') == param('sent') == 'yes'` in the OP example. Here's a fix:
`return (location.search.split(new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '='))[1] || '').split('&')[0]`;
Also note that you cannot tell if the param exists because you get empty string for missing parameters.

Comment: // (to force the full key to exist instead of only the last part of the key)
`return (location.search.split('?' + name + '=')[1] || location.search.split('&' + name + '=')[1] || '').split('&')[0];`

Answer (score 49):

Using `URLSearchParams`:

```
var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(params.get('name'));
```

Be careful about the compatibility (Mostly it's fine, but IE and Edge, may be different story, check this for compatible reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: URLSearchParams replaces special character "+" with a space. So if your url param has a "+" in it, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 48):

May be its too late. But this method is very easy and simple

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.url.js"></script>

<!-- URL:  www.example.com/correct/?message=done&year=1990 -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.url.attr('protocol')  // --> Protocol: "http"
    $.url.attr('path')      // --> host: "www.example.com"
    $.url.attr('query')         // --> path: "/correct/"
    $.url.attr('message')       // --> query: "done"
    $.url.attr('year')      // --> query: "1990"
});
```

**UPDATE**
Requires the url plugin : [plugins.jquery.com/url](https://plugins.jquery.com/url/)
Thanks -Ripounet

Comment: Whoever decides on this should check the repo first. Usage has changed.
$.url.attr('message') becomes $.url("query") and it only gives the full query!
To get only one parameter I had to:
$.url("query").split("=")[1]

[url github link](https://github.com/websanova/js-url)

Answer (score 41):

Or you can use this neat little function, because ***why overcomplicated solutions?***

```
function getQueryParam(param, defaultValue = undefined) {
    location.search.substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .some(function(item) { // returns first occurence and stops
            return item.split("=")[0] == param && (defaultValue = item.split("=")[1], true)
        })
    return defaultValue
}
```

which looks even better when simplified and onelined:

## tl;dr one-line solution

```
var queryDict = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]})
```

```
result:
queryDict['sent'] // undefined or 'value'
```

### But what if you have got *encoded characters* or *multivalued keys*?

You better see this answer: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152762/985454)

*Sneak peak*

```
"?a=1&b=2&c=3&d&e&a=5&a=t%20e%20x%20t&e=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dståle%26car%3Dsaab"
> queryDict
a: ["1", "5", "t e x t"]
b: ["2"]
c: ["3"]
d: [undefined]
e: [undefined, "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"]

> queryDict["a"][1] // "5"
> queryDict.a[1] // "5"
```

Comment: string split is likely to be faster than regex too. Not that that is a factor considering the url would only be parsed once.

Comment: This is the solution (the first one) that worked perfectly for me across browsers - thank you!

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Great to hear that, thank you! Anyway, be aware that this is a very simple solution, if you get complicated url params that contain special characters, you better check the link provided.

Comment: @Qwerty yup - my use case is very simple where the parameter is always the same, etc (basically exactly what the OP asked for) Thanks again!

Comment: The  "return param" in the first example means the URL query parameter name is returned when it's not specified in the URL. This seems strange.

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken Interesting, I fixed it, anyway, it's rather very dumb solution, the one at the bottom which supports encoded characters and arrays is much better.

Answer (score 14):

This one is simple and worked for me

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

so if your url is http://www.yoursite.com?city=4

try this

```
console.log($.urlParam('city'));
```

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you might want to give [Dentist JS](https://github.com/kelvintaywl/dentist.js/blob/master/js/dentist.js) a look? (disclaimer: I wrote the code)

**code:**

```
document.URL == "http://helloworld.com/quotes?id=1337&author=kelvin&message=hello"
var currentURL = document.URL;
var params = currentURL.extract();
console.log(params.id); // 1337
console.log(params.author) // "kelvin"
console.log(params.message) // "hello"
```

with Dentist JS, you can basically call the extract() function on all strings (e.g., document.URL.extract() ) and you get back a HashMap of all parameters found. It's also customizable to deal with delimiters and all.

Minified version < 1kb

Answer (score 6):

I hope this will help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function getParameters() {
     var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
       params = searchString.split("&"),
       hash = {};

     if (searchString == "") return {};
     for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
       var val = params[i].split("=");
       hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
     }

     return hash;
   }

    $(window).load(function() {
      var param = getParameters();
      if (typeof param.sent !== "undefined") {
        // Do something.
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xy7cX/

API:

- `inArray` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

This should help `:)`

**code**

```
var url = "http://myurl.com?sent=yes"

var pieces = url.split("?");
alert(pieces[1] + " ===== " + $.inArray("sent=yes", pieces));
```

Comment: only works for a single var -- the & would throw it off -- could be extended with regex

Answer (score 5):

This will give you a nice object to work with

```
    function queryParameters () {
        var result = {};

        var params = window.location.search.split(/\?|\&/);

        params.forEach( function(it) {
            if (it) {
                var param = it.split("=");
                result[param[0]] = param[1];
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```

And then;

```
    if (queryParameters().sent === 'yes') { .....
```

Comment: split(/\?|\&/) this means

Answer (score 5):

This might be overkill, but there is a pretty popular library now available for parsing URIs, called [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js).

### Example

```js
var uri = "http://example.org/foo.html?technology=jquery&technology=css&blog=stackoverflow";
var components = URI.parse(uri);
var query = URI.parseQuery(components['query']);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "URI = " + uri;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>technology = " + query['technology'];

// If you look in your console, you will see that this library generates a JS array for multi-valued queries!
console.log(query['technology']);
console.log(query['blog']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.17.0/URI.min.js"></script>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function GetRequestParam(param)
{
 var res = null;
 try{
  var qs = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));//get everything after then '?' in URI
  var ar = qs.split('&');
  $.each(ar, function(a, b){
   var kv = b.split('=');
   if(param === kv[0]){
    res = kv[1];
    return false;//break loop
   }
  });
 }catch(e){}
 return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So simple you can use any url and get value

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
// query string: ?first=value1&second=&value2
var foo = getParameterByName('first'); // "value1"
var bar = getParameterByName('second'); // "value2"
```

Note: If a parameter is present several times (?first=value1&second=value2), you will get the first value (value1) and second value as (value2).

Answer (score 3):

There's this great library:
https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

which allows you to do simply

```
url = 'http://example.com?sent=yes';
sent = $.url(url).param('sent');
if (typeof sent != 'undefined') { // sent exists
   if (sent == 'yes') { // sent is equal to yes
     // ...
   }
}
```

The example is assuming you're using jQuery. You could also use it just as plain javascript, the syntax would then be a little different.

Comment: This library is not maintained any more, however I use it and it's great. Make sure you use param not attr to get those query string parameters, as the author has included in their example.

Answer (score 3):

```
http://example.com?sent=yes
```

Best solution [here](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript).

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.href);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, '    '));
};
```

With the function above, you can get individual parameter values:

```
getUrlParameter('sent');
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is based on [Gazoris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2601258/gazoris)'s answer, but URL decodes the parameters so they can be used when they contain data other than numbers and letters:

```
function urlParam(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    // Need to decode the URL parameters, including putting in a fix for the plus sign
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417399
    return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another example with using [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) library.

Example answers the questions exactly as asked.

```js
var url = 'http://example.com?sent=yes';
var urlParams = new URI(url).search(true);
// 1. Does sent exist?
var sendExists = urlParams.sent !== undefined;
// 2. Is it equal to "yes"?
var sendIsEqualtToYes = urlParams.sent == 'yes';

// output results in readable form
// not required for production
if (sendExists) {
  console.log('Url has "sent" param, its value is "' + urlParams.sent + '"');
  if (urlParams.sent == 'yes') {
    console.log('"Sent" param is equal to "yes"');
  } else {
    console.log('"Sent" param is not equal to "yes"');
  }
} else {
  console.log('Url hasn\'t "sent" param');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.18.2/URI.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript version of Sameer's answer

```
getUrlParameter = (sParam) ->
  sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1)
  sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&')
  i = 0
  while i < sURLVariables.length
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=')
    if sParameterName[0] == sParam
      return sParameterName[1]
    i++
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement to Sameer's answer, cache params into closure to avoid parsing and looping through all parameters each time calling

```
var getURLParam = (function() {
    var paramStr = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).substring(1);
    var paramSegs = paramStr.split('&');
    var params = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < paramSegs.length; i++) {
        var paramSeg = paramSegs[i].split('=');
        params[paramSeg[0]] = paramSeg[1];
    }
    console.log(params);
    return function(key) {
        return params[key];
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it works.
http://codesheet.org/codesheet/NF246Tzs

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
    });
return vars;
}


var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla JavaScript, you could easily take the params (location.search), get the substring (without the ?) and turn it into an array, by splitting it by '&'.

As you iterate through urlParams, you could then split the string again with '=' and add it to the 'params' object as object[elmement[0]] = element[1].  Super simple and easy to access.

http://www.website.com/?error=userError&type=handwritten

```
            var urlParams = location.search.substring(1).split('&'),
                params = {};

            urlParams.forEach(function(el){
                var tmpArr = el.split('=');
                params[tmpArr[0]] = tmpArr[1];
            });


            var error = params['error'];
            var type = params['type'];
```

Answer (score 1):

What if there is & in URL parameter like filename="p&g.html"&uid=66

In this case the 1st function will not work properly. So I modified the code

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sURLVariables = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&'), sParameterName, i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly I'm adding my answer to an over-answered question, but this has the advantages of:

-- Not depending on any outside libraries, including jQuery

-- Not polluting global function namespace, by extending 'String'

-- Not creating any global data and doing unnecessary processing after match found

-- Handling encoding issues, and accepting (assuming) non-encoded parameter name

-- Avoiding explicit `for` loops

```
String.prototype.urlParamValue = function() {
    var desiredVal = null;
    var paramName = this.valueOf();
    window.location.search.substring(1).split('&').some(function(currentValue, _, _) {
        var nameVal = currentValue.split('=');
        if ( decodeURIComponent(nameVal[0]) === paramName ) {
            desiredVal = decodeURIComponent(nameVal[1]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    return desiredVal;
};
```

Then you'd use it as:

```
var paramVal = "paramName".urlParamValue() // null if no match
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a specific parameter from a specific url:

```
function findParam(url, param){
  var check = "" + param;
  if(url.search(check )>=0){
      return url.substring(url.search(check )).split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
  }
}  

var url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/example?id=1&order_no=114&invoice_no=254";  
alert(findParam(url,"order_no"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that uses jQuery and JSON, so you can access the parameter values through an object.

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var param = {};
if(loc.indexOf('?') > -1)
{
    var params = loc.substr(loc.indexOf('?')+1, loc.length).split("&");

    var stringJson = "{";
    for(var i=0;i<params.length;i++)
    {
        var propVal = params[i].split("=");
        var paramName = propVal[0];
        var value = propVal[1];
        stringJson += "\""+paramName+"\": \""+value+"\"";
        if(i != params.length-1) stringJson += ",";
    }
    stringJson += "}";
    // parse string with jQuery parseJSON
    param = $.parseJSON(stringJson);
}
```

Assuming your URL is `http://example.com/?search=hello+world&language=en&page=3`

After that it's only a matter of using the parameters like this:

```
param.language
```

to return

```
en
```

The most useful usage of this is to run it at page load and make use of a global variable to use the parameters anywhere you might need them.

If your parameter contains numeric values then just parse the value.

```
parseInt(param.page)
```

If there are no parameters `param` will just be an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript and without regular expressions:

```js
Object.fromEntries(new URL(url).searchParams);
```

The `Object.fromEntries()` static method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Answer (score -1):

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Comment: & is wrongly encoded as "&amp;" in above answer, refer to correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25359264/73630

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to show my codes:

```
function (name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
  results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}

Comment: You need to pad out the answer with an explanation on how this helps the OP (not that they need it since they have 24 other answers to choose from and have already solved their issue).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var RequestQuerystring;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query = window.location.search.substring(1);

    RequestQuerystring = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
        RequestQuerystring[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

**RequestQuerystring** is now an object with all you parameters

Answer (score -1):

Get the param from a string:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'urlParam', {

    value: function (param) {

    "use strict";

    var str = this.trim();

    var regex = "[\?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)";

    var results = new RegExp(regex, "i").exec(str);

    return (results !== null) ? results[1] : '';

    }
});
```

to use:

```
var src = 'http://your-url.com/?param=value'

console.log(src.urlParam(param)); // returns 'value'
```

Answer (score -1):

I Hope to use the full simple REG Exp

```
  function getQueryString1(param) {
    return decodeURIComponent(
        (location.search.match(RegExp("[?|&]"+param+'=(.+?)(&|$)'))||[,null])[1]
    );
  }
```