# Javascript alert not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, alerts

Does anyone know how can I resolve the following: I want the form input by the user, to be alerted in a different HTML file.

This is what I wrote so far. It works for the id called 'name', but I dont know why it does not for the 'position'.

"index.html" file:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        position = document.getElementById("position").value;

        window.location.replace("signature.html");
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form class="formulario" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
      Position:  <input type="text" name="position" id="position"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate Signature">
</form>
```

"signature.html" file - notice the alert(name) and the alert(position) => the alert(name) works, but not the alert(position). I want to understand how to fix that please.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="signature_general">
    <div class = "signature_middle">
        <div id = "signature_details">
        <font size="2px">Regards,</font><br>
        <b><font color="#808080" size="3px" id="nameInput">Francisco Jurado</font></b><br>
        <font size="2px" id="posInput">Accounting Systems Team Leader</font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    alert(name);
    alert(position);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks very much

Edit: I have noticed that I am getting an error, in which "position" is "undefined". Does anyone knows?

Comment: Obviously, you hasn't decalred the varriables for 'name' and 'position'. try this: var name='test1', position='test2'; alert(name); alert(position);

Comment: @Sphinx edit: do you mean in the "signature.html" file?

Comment: @Sphinx I have tried the following (perhaps it's not what you mean): declaring in the "index.html" file, as follow:   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
     var position = document.getElementById("position").value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your html file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form class="formulario" action="signature.html" method="get">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
      Position:  <input type="text" name="position" id="position"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate Signature">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

And your signature.html file as :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="signature_general">
    <div class = "signature_middle">
        <div id = "signature_details">
        <font size="2px">Regards,</font><br>
        <b><font color="#808080" size="3px" id="nameInput">Francisco Jurado</font></b><br>
        <font size="2px" id="posInput">Accounting Systems Team Leader</font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  var values = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')
  var name = values[0].split('=')[1]
  var position = values[1].split('=')[1]
  alert(name)
  alert(position)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: darthweb. I noticed that if I input a value with spaces, instead of displaying "hello world", it displays "hello+world". How do I fix this?

Comment: Also the @, is displayed as "%40". Thanks.

Comment: Edit: Resolved with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717557/remove-plus-sign-in-url-query-string

Answer (score 0):

That name you are setting in `index.html` is not the same name you are printing in the alert of `signature.html`.

You can see this by renaming `name` to `name2` in both places.

If you want to pass those variables from one page to another, I suggest using query strings [how to exchange variables between two HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages)