# Javascript Parser for UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I have looked through many questions and do not see one which worked. I am working with `UCWA API` responses where it is returning the following for incoming messages:

data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,hi+maya

The objective is to capture the input text "hi maya". I have tried doing a `split` on the `string` to capture everything after the comma and I have also tried `decodeURIComponent(msg.msgIn)`. I have also looked at buffer for `nodejs`.
Neither one is working, so would appreciate help on how to parse this.

Also, I have looked at similar posts here and it is related to downloading a file. I don't want to have to download a file - just directly take the string from the api response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent` [doesn't "decode" `+`es into spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417399/179125). Go figure. The solution is to do that yourself first:

```js
function decodeDataUri(uri) {
  const data = uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',') + 1);
  return decodeURIComponent(data.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

console.log(decodeDataUri('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,hi+maya'));
```