# How to copy data from one form to another?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have forms:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form1">
    [many inputs, selects etc - form is used to filter the displayed results]
</form>

[content]
<table ...>
  <tr>
     <td>...<td>
     <td>
       <form action="" method="post" id="form2">
         [some inputs on row]
         <input type="submit" name="updaterow" value="Update row" />
       </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to copy data of inputs from form1 to form2 when I click submit button on form2. How to do it?

Comment: How are you matching the inputs up?

Comment: Input names have unique names

Comment: Are from elements in both forms have same name?

Comment: No - every forms element have unique name on all html body

Answer (score 0):

if both forms have same elements name then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1490431/1934041)
plugin like :-

```
$("#form2").values($("#form1").values());
```

if not then--
here is working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/yJaU4/3/)