# How to keep the form condition on browser go back and go forward button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

I am using grails 2.4.2 version which uses HTML 5. I have some form element based on some condition. Such as District, Thana. When I select the district then I am hiding thana and when selecting thana then hiding district. This works fine.

But when I click the go back button of the browser then it shows both the field. I want to keep the form element condition as I expected when a user click the go back button of the browser. How can I implement it?

Comment: Personally think this is probably not designed well. You could maybe provide jquery-ui-tabs and illeminate the need to go back/forward. None the less much easier than stated so far (caching etc) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489486/jquery-plugin-to-serialize-a-form-and-also-restore-populate-the-form using jquery to serialize form and take that along with you  might be an option. If they click next surely you are capturing that so store it and provide own back buttons that regenerates it through grails rather than javascript caching. That's how I would go about it

Answer (score 0):

Store all the fields in localStorage for the session, and then when the page is loaded, use JavaScript to load everything from localStorage.

Comment: Cookies work. I would use localStorage because it save it for the session.

Answer (score -1):

1. save state when location changed
2. use state when page loaded

Comment: any idea how to save state and use it

Comment: use native browser api. cookie or localStorage.

Comment: or if you already use jQuery, check Persist jQuery plugin. It give you same functionality with 'key-value' format

Comment: This is pretty vague.